# Minipage in table has strange inter-row spacing

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I have a `pandoc` generated latex table (from markdown) which looks like the following:

[image]

What I dont get is how to properly space the rows, lets say with `12pt`. The `\tabularnewline[12pt]` has no effect? Why doesnt it work?
How can I space the content rows (not the header) correctly?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
\caption{TODO Title einfügen}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.39\columnwidth}\raggedright
as dasd asd asd \strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.52\columnwidth}\raggedright
AA-Modell\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.39\columnwidth}\raggedright
asd asd asd asd asd \strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.52\columnwidth}\raggedright
AA-Modell\strut
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.39\columnwidth}\raggedright
Was ist passiert?\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.52\columnwidth}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}
\item
  ajkshd kjahsd kjhaskjhdkj haskdjhaklsjdaklsjhd klajshd lkajshd klajshd kahs dlkha sd
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline[12pt]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.39\columnwidth}\raggedright
Wie fühle ich mich? Und du?\strut
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.52\columnwidth}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}
\item
  ajkshd lkajsd löajks döljasdökjasöldkjasöld aölsdj aölsjd ölasjd ölajs d
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead if nesting minipages inside of the table cells, you could directly use p type columns of the appropriate widths.

Comment: I could, unfortunately pandoc produces this...

Comment: I wonder what version of pandoc you used to create this? The output is quite different from the current version's (2.11.2), and the current version does not have this spacing bug.

Comment: I used 2.11.0.4, I will test with 2.11.2 soon, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't' use `minipage`s in table, rather use `p` columns and for `itemize` list in the second columns rather use `enumitem` packages and its ability of customizations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,      % new
            booktabs, longtable,
            makecell}   % new
\usepackage{enumitem}   % new
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % new
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep=0pt,
                 leftmargin=*,
                 label=\textbullet,
                 after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                 before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                 }
                      }

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{longtable}[]{@{} >{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr0.45\columnwidth-\tabcolsep}
                            >{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr0.55\columnwidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\caption{TODO Title einfügen}\tabularnewline
    \toprule
as dasd asd asd 
    &   AA-Modell       \tabularnewline
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \toprule
asd asd asd asd asd 
    &   AA-Modell       \tabularnewline
    \midrule
\endhead
%
Was ist passiert? 
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   ajkshd kjahsd kjhaskjhdkj haskdjhaklsjdaklsjhd klajshd lkajshd klajshd kahs dlkha sd
        \end{itemize}   \tabularnewline
Wie fühle ich mich? Und du?
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   ajkshd lkajsd löajks döljasdökjasöldkjasöld aölsdj aölsjd ölasjd ölajs d
        \end{itemize}   \tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote,

> What I don't get is how to properly space the rows, let's say with 12pt. The `\tabularnewline[12pt]` has no effect?

Assuming that `12pt` is a stand-in for `\baselineskip`, you *could* -- but shouldn't -- replace `\tabularnewline[12pt]` with `\\ \\`. That ends up inserting way too much whitespace, though. Since you use the `booktabs` package, a much better solution is to use `\addlinespace`. I therefore suggest that you replace

```
\tabularnewline[12pt]
```

with

```
\\ \addlinespace
```

A full MWE and its output -- note that I've tried to clean up your somewhat unruly code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} P{0.39} P{0.52} @{}}

% headers and footers:
\caption{TODO Title einfügen} \\
\toprule
as dasd asd asd & AA-Modell \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
asd asd asd asd asd AA-Modell \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of longtable:
Was ist passiert? & 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize} \raggedright
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    ajkshd kjahsd kjhaskjhdkj haskdjhaklsjdaklsjhd klajshd lkajshd klajshd kahs dlkha sd
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage} 
%% \\ \\         % <-- not good
\\ \addlinespace % <-- much better 

Wie fühle ich mich? Und du? & 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize} \raggedright
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    ajkshd lkajsd löajks döljasdökjasöldkjasöld aölsdj aölsjd ölasjd ölajs d \strut
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage} \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!è This is very helpful!